# Share task list between people using iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I'd like to create an iOS app for shopping lists (yeah, one more), **allowing synchronization between 2 (or more) iCloud users** (like what Apple does with shared calendars).

Any idea how I should structure my data to accomplish that ? Can I do that with the tools iCloud offers at the moment in iOS 8?

EDIT: I'm especially interested in the **sharing** part of the process: how to "invite" other users (as in the Calendar app to "Add Person" for a shared calendar), or maybe include Family members (as declared in iTunes) in 
the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud app data is sandboxed and not accessible by other users https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html

In CloudKit there is a private and a public database. when you write to the public database, then that data could be read by others. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/

Cloud Kit may be your best option

Comment: But keep in mind that CloudKit only has "private" and "public" data. There's no "limited to the following people..." option.

Comment: If you use the public data you can ensure that you only query the data that your users should be allowed to see.

Comment: Yes but how would I specifically "invite" people to share data ?

Comment: Ok found it : it's in WWDC 2014 video "Advanced CloudKit"

Comment: This is good and works, but wait the quota for the public cloudkit gors against the app owner, not the individual.